# Why won't Gmail allow me to change my profile picture?

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-workspace, google-account, profile-picture

I've tried many and multiple times to change my profile picture. all it says is, "Sorry, you can't change this photo for this account." It'll keep saying that over and over again. I hate my profile picture. I just wanted to change it because everyone in my online classes are making fun of me for having this profile pic.

I've tried going through "About Me" and it just won't let me. I just want to change it and get out of this terrible bullying. Please, if you know how to do it, please notify me.

Comment: What kind of Google account do you have? Is it a `yourname@gmail.com` account, or a `yourname@your.school` account? If it was set up by your school, the system administrator at your school might be able to help you.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 12 times. While the question doesn't mention the type of account, due to the context, it's fair to assume that it's a managed account. At the time that this question was asked, Google managed accounts were handled by G Suite administrators, now Google Workspace administrators.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your Gmail account was provided for you by your school. If so, the system administrator might have disabled the ability for users to change their profile pictures.

But whoever is managing Google Workspace (the administrator) at your school should be able to help you.
First, find out who the administrator is. It might be ([source](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960?hl=en)):

- The person who gave you your username
- Someone in your IT department or Help desk (at a company or school)
- The person who manages your email service or web site (in a small business or club)

The tell the administrator that he or she needs to log in to Google Workspace's administration console and [change or reset your profile picture from there](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/3405984?hl=en).

Answer (score -1):

Change your Gmail profile picture by checking out this: [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/35529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: The Google Support article you're linking may have all the necessary information, but please include all the relevant information _in your answer_. A link may go dead at any time, leaving your answer useless.

Answer (score -2):

f can’t Change photo on account TELL PEOPLE```To change name or photo on google accounts with G-suite you have to go to admin.google.com and under profiles allow yourself to change photo and name too if you want. It will change your You-tube name also if you do this.